# Designing user table for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing a user table for my current project. I want to add a column to user table where I can store information whether user was deleted or not. I'm thinking about adding only one datetime column so if date is set that means user was deleted at this date and time. Other common approach is to add additional deletion flag 1 or 0. Do I need deletion flag looking at it from performance/scalability perspective?

Comment: Consider a LastUpdated (DateTime), and isActive (bit). Last updated can be used for other changes that might happen, and if they are inactive, you can assume that last updated was the date it happened. You could go with isDeleted, but I feel like Deleted means you wouldn't have a row..

Comment: @prescott looks like we both were thinking of the same thing at the same time!

Comment: I like that idea. Like you said I have additional information about when record was updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the deleteFlag and also a lastUpdate column. Whenever the deleteFlag value changes you can set the lastUpdate column to `NOW()`. So you will know if the user is deleted/undeleted and when. Adding two such columns should not affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

#### From the perspective of performance and scalability:

The presence of an additional boolean column shouldn't make much difference as your application scales if you index your deleted timestamp column.  The single column should work out just fine, and if you get tired of having to use the condition:

```
WHERE deleted_date IS NOT NULL
```

... all the time to determine which users are active, you might consider just creating views for that:

```
CREATE VIEW active_users AS
(
SELECT
  username,
  name,
  email
FROM users
WHERE deleted_date IS NOT NULL
);
```

#### From the perspective of ease-of-use

I would probably use the additional boolean column just to make querying a little tidier.  However, it adds a little complexity in your application code to remember to update both columns.  Alternatively, you can create a trigger to set the timestamp when the boolean is updated to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use datetime as flag field. And if you have a lot of users, use non-blocking table altering: [oak-online-alter-table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html)